# How to perform different action for same button in table cell swift?

Tags: swift, uitableview

I need to perform different action for a button in table cell, Each button has different text as per it's index path.

I need to show different drop-down options on each button and perform the selection of the drop-down

[image: Check this image for better understanding]

Comment: Are you using same data modal if yes then on button tap get that value US, European and accordingly show next screen

Comment: Give tag to button and in action you can handle your action on button tag

Comment: @PravinTate I'm using single popup model, with different data each time

Answer (score 0):

You can check this before performing the action you can check what type of button is.

Comment: As this button is on custom table cell so it would be a single button.

Comment: Sorry for late response. you need to create a separate class for the cell, and add that to the cell, and in the cell class you can take action for every, as we are doing in viewcontroller class

Answer (score 0):

Add a tag to each button so you can determine which one it is when pressed.

You can access it by button.tag

Comment: as this is in table we can just give index path as tag for it, which is the approach we use all the time.